# smarty arrays multidimensional

Tags: smarty

I want to access the value of thumbnail using Smarty but I need some help to loop through this array

```
Array (
  [photo] => Array (
    [ID] => 10
    [Listing_ID] => 10
    [Position] => 1
    [Photo] => listing_photo10_1710730681321487877.jpg
    [Thumbnail] => listing_thumbnail10_11485755481321487877.jpg
    [Original] => listing_orig10_19751362711321487877.jpg
    [Description] =>
    [Type] => sale
    [Status] => active
    [Kind_ID] => 1
    [Account_ID] => 9
    [Plan_ID] => 1
    [Pay_date] => 2011-11-17 04:57:45
    [Featured_ID] => 0
    [Featured_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [Last_show] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [Crossed] =>
    [Shows] => 0
    [Date] => 2011-11-17 04:57:45
    [Rating] => 0
    [Rating_votes] => 0
    [Cron] => 0
    [Cron_notified] => 0
    [Cron_featured] => 0
    [categories] =>
    [headline] => test
    [price] => 1|euro
    [description] => asdas
    [condition] => 1
    [title] =>
    [lf_site_url] =>
    [description_add] =>
    [contact_number] => 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: looks wackey but due to my less knowledge about smarty i dont know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: any idea dan ? i modified my code that i tried      div id="display_image">
        {foreach from=$products_images item=photo name=photo}
            {foreach from=$photo item=thumbnail name=thumbnail}
            {$thumbnail|print_r}
        <a href="{$smarty.const.RL_URL_HOME}files/{$thumbnail}">
        <img src="{$smarty.const.RL_URL_HOME}files/{$thumbnail.thumbnail}" width="87" height="65" style="margin:3px;" /> </a>
    {/foreach}
     {/foreach}
    
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="display_image">
{foreach from=$products_images item=photo name=photo}
{foreach from=$photo item=thumbnail name=thumbnail}
{$thumbnail|print_r}
<a href="{$smarty.const.RL_URL_HOME}files/{$thumbnail.Photo}">
<img src="{$smarty.const.RL_URL_HOME}files/{$thumbnail.Thumbnail}" width="87" height="65"          style="margin:3px;" /> </a>
{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

try this